# OpenGL program compiles but doesn't start correctly

Tags: c++, opengl, freeglut

I'm trying out OpenGL and C++, and I followed [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3aJ8OR1C6pk) on writing my program (my code is exactly the same as his). I also followed the instructions on the freeglut website [here](https://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/computing/using-glut-with-mingw/) to set up freeglut, compile, and link my program. The source code compiles with no problem, but when I try running the exe I get an error. The only reason I could think of is that I'm not using an IDE, so I'm probably missing some compilation steps or missing some command line arguments when running the exe, which the IDE would have done automatically. Can someone tell me what I need to do to run my program correctly?

Here's my code:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

void init() {
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}

void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();


    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB);

    glutInitWindowPosition(200, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);

    glutCreateWindow("Window 1");

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    init();

    glutMainLoop();
}
```

When I compile I run

```
gcc -c -o hello.o hello.cpp -I"C:\MinGW\include"
gcc -o hello.exe hello.o -L"C:\MinGW\lib" -lfreeglut -lopengl32 -Wl,--subsystem,windows
```

Then I try to run `hello.exe` but I only get an error message "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)".

BTW I saw this [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27275823/program-with-opengl-compiles-but-doesnt-run) but I've tried putting the dll in the same directory (it was there from the start) but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Your tag says `c++`, your file name extension is `.cpp`, but compile as C (`gcc`). So, is it C or C++? If it is C, you should add `void` as function arguments. Please run your application in a debugger (e.g. `gdb`) to gain more information, and show the backtrace.

Comment: 0xc000007b means invalid image format. Make sure all of your stack (OS, compiler, dlls) is the same architecture. Can you run a non-OpenGL hello world program?

Comment: @Erlkoenig `gcc` command compiles C++ files as C++. It is rather impossible to run in a debugger something that would not even start.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Yes, but C++ code isn't linked correctly by `gcc`. Don't know about the details, but it _could_ just be the reason for the error... Anyways, trying a Non-OpenGL-program is a good idea.

Comment: @Erlkoenig no, any problem would result in linker errors, not runtime errors. True, one needs to use g++ for linking C++ programs, However since the program doesn't use any of the C++ library facilities, it can get away with gcc linking. I've just tried this exact program with these commands (using gcc) and it compiles, links and runs for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using the 32 bit freeglut dll (instead of the 64 bit dll) in my project fixed the problem.